# I can't webscrap a table with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrap a  table from this website: https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas

But it will always return an empty list. I've seen many people had this issue, but the solutions are not working.

This is my code.

```
target <- "https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas" %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
remotes::install_github("tidyverse/rvest")

library(rvest)

"https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas" %>% 
  read_html_live() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  pluck(1) 

# A tibble: 28 × 7
   Ano   Norma    Data  `Meta (%)` Tamanhodo intervalo …¹ Intervalode tolerânc…² Inflação efetiva(Var…³
   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                 
 1 1999  Resoluç… 30/6… 8          2                      6-10                   8,94                  
 2 2000  Resoluç… 30/6… ​6          ​2                      4-8                    5,97                  
 3 2001  Resoluç… 30/6… ​4          ​2                      2-6                    7,67                  
 4 2002  Resoluç… 28/6… 3,5        2                      1,5-5,5                12,53                 
 5 2003* Resoluç… 28/6… 3,254      22,5                   1,25-5,251,5-6,5       9,309,30              
 6 2004* Resoluç… 27/6… 3,755,5    2,52,5                 1,25-6,253-8           7,60                  
 7 2005  Resoluç… 25/6… 4,5        2,5                    2-7                    5,69                  
 8 2006  Resoluç… 30/6… 4,5        ​2,0                    2,5-6,5                3,14                  
 9 2007  Resoluç… 23/6… 4,5        ​2,0                    2,5-6,5                4,46                  
10 2008  Resoluç… 29/6… 4,5        ​2,0                    2,5-6,5                5,90                  
# ℹ 18 more rows
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Tamanhodo intervalo +/- (p.p.)`, ²​`Intervalode tolerância (%)`,
#   ³​`Inflação efetiva(Variação do IPCA, %)`
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```